# FCM HTTP v1: how to get access token using Go?

Tags: firebase, go, google-api, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

In order to send Firebase Cloud Messaging with Go, we need to place the access token in the HTTP request header.

On Firebase documentation,
there are examples on how to retrieve the access token using *Node.JS*, *Python* and *Java*:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

can anyone show the get the access token using **Go**?

There seems to be many Go packages about Firebase/Google authentication. It's very confusing to understand which ones should be used:

- firebase.google.com/go
- firebase.google.com/go/auth
- github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go
- google.golang.org/api/option
- golang.org/x/oauth2
- golang.org/x/oauth2/google
- github.com/google/google-api-go-client

Comment: Hi. Sorry, could you point me to the documentation where it says that you need an *access token* to send FCM messages from Go? AFAIK, you should only need the *Server Key* and a valid target to send an FCM message.

Comment: On the newer protocol FCM v1 HTTP API, you need an access token, as reported here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

Comment: Okay. I did a quick read through. I haven't experienced using FCM from a Service account, nor using Go lang. But basing from the [Git guide](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/GettingStarted.md) link, the package that you would most need is `golang.org/x/oauth2`. Instantiating the GoogleCredentials is something I can't figure out tho. Sorry wasn't able to help out.

Comment: Hey @DanieleB. There was a recent vid uploaded by Firebase about [getting auth tokens via the Admin SDK using Go](https://youtu.be/VuqEOjBMQWE). Not sure if it would help, your post came to mind when I saw it. Good luck.

Comment: @AL. thanks. This is the same content that was published on the firebase blog in August: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/introducing-firebase-admin-sdk-for-go.html but these `custom tokens` seem to be something different from the `access tokens` that are required for Cloud Messsaging.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the go firebase SDK to add FCM HTTP v1.

For now it's almost finished, i have to write tests and integration tests, you can check the code here : https://github.com/chemidy/firebase-admin-go/tree/fcm/messaging

I will finish tests and send a PR maybe next week, (it's a little bit tricky to test on ios + android + web)

Answer (score 1):

FCM httpv1 use JSON file for it credentials.

Download it first, then move it to your project.
[download JSON credentials in your firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aZhH.png)

second, do :

```
go get "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
```

then use this method to get token

```
const firebaseScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"

type tokenProvider struct {
    tokenSource oauth2.TokenSource
}

// newTokenProvider function to get token for fcm-send
func newTokenProvider(credentialsLocation string) (*tokenProvider, error) {
    jsonKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile(credentialsLocation)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("fcm: failed to read credentials file at: " + credentialsLocation)
    }
    cfg, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(jsonKey, firebaseScope)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("fcm: failed to get JWT config for the firebase.messaging scope")
    }
    ts := cfg.TokenSource(context.Background())
    return &tokenProvider{
        tokenSource: ts,
    }, nil
}

func (src *tokenProvider) token() (string, error) {
    token, err := src.tokenSource.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.New("fcm: failed to generate Bearer token")
    }
    return token.AccessToken, nil
}
```

Then call it in your FCM-Send method :

```
tp, err := newTokenProvider("yourJSONFileLocation")
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
token, err := tp.token()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

last, add it to header :

```
r.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

i am put header Authorization by used volly

```
  @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headerMap.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + key);
                Log.v(TAG,"getHeaders "+headerMap);

                return headerMap;
            }
```

but send Authorization=Bearer  Add..

how change to current 
Authorization:Bearer